# How do I create a font in Monotouch?

Tags: fonts, xamarin.ios

How do I create a font in Monotouch?

I want to specify the font family, size, and style (e.g., Courier, bold, 25).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have a `UIButton` named `_woot`:

`_woot.Font = UIFont.FromName ("Courier-Bold", 25);`

If you can figure out a font name, use this code to print them all out:

```
            string fonts = "--------------------------------------\n";
            var fontFamilies = new List<String> (UIFont.FamilyNames);
            fontFamilies.Sort ();
            foreach (var familyName in fontFamilies) {
                foreach (var fontName in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName (familyName)) {
                    fonts += familyName;
                    fonts += "\t";
                    fonts += fontName;
                    fonts += "\n";
                }
                fonts += "--------------------------------------\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine (fonts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and example code!  I think the part I was missing was that the font name contains a dash with the font style.

Answer (score 1):

In code, Use the [UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.  Or do it using Interface Builder.  Those are the Apple docs - there aren't a lot of MT specific examples of using fonts, although [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Standard_Controls/Fonts/Enumerate_Fonts?highlight=uifont) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the list of fonts!